# getting the View of custom Adapter android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

How can I get the view of custom adapter?. I know that I can get the view using the onclicklistener but I dont want to use it also it will give me an error of null. I have this code that get the view of the listView items but the thing is I wont let me animate it

Code:

```
result_list.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {
                private float startX;
                private float startY;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        startX = event.getX();
                        startY = event.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                        float endX = event.getX();
                        float endY = event.getY();
                        if (isAClick(startX, endX, startY, endY)) { 
                            Log.d("click", "clicked");   
                            //result_list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                            itemPositionView = customAdapter.getView(position, null, result_list);
                            itemPositionView.animate().setDuration(300).translationX(widthListView).alpha(0).
                            withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,new Intent().putExtra("bussStopCode", data.get(i).getStopCode()).putExtra("bussStopName", data.get(i).getStopName()));
                                    ////int get 1
                                    //data.remove(i);
                                    listLastPostion = position;
                                    //customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    //view.setTranslationX(0);

                                    //Log.d("data",conreq.getCollectedData().getBusRouteSetData().get(temporaryInteger - 1).getRouteHeading());
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("busdestination", conreq.getCollectedData().getBusRouteSetData().get(position).getRouteHeading());
                                    bundle.putString("busnumber", conreq.getCollectedData().getBusRouteSetData().get(position).getRouteNo());
                                    Fragment fragment = new FragmentNextTripForStop();
                                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                    FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                    fragmentManager.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_left_anim_x_left,R.anim.right_left_anim_x_right,R.anim.left_right_anim_x_left,R.anim.left_right_anim_x_right);
                                    fragmentManager.add(R.id.fragment_searched_data_xml, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                                   // finish();
                                    //overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_left_anim_x_left,R.anim.right_left_anim_x_right);

                                }
                            }); 
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

position is the one I took from the onclicklister cause When I take the view from the onclickListerner it will give me an error of null

```
result_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, final View view,
                     final int i, long i2) {
                //result_list.setEnabled(false);
                getViewPosition(i);

            }});
```

I also took the final but still gives me an error on view not on position

```
    10-15 02:22:44.411: E/InputEventReceiver(13793): Exception dispatching input event.
10-15 02:22:44.411: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13793): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
10-15 02:22:44.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13793): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-15 02:22:44.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13793):  at com.example.octranspodestination1.MainActivity$FragmentMainClass$4.onTouch(MainActivity.java:384)
10-15 02:22:44.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13793):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7241)
10-15 02:22:44.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13793):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2179)
10-15 02:22:44.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13793):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1914)
10-15 02:22:44.421: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13793):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
```

line 384 is this:

```
itemPositionView.animate().setDuration(300).translationX(widthListView).alpha(0).
```

Comment: you have the view as the param here `final View view` in `onItemClick`

Comment: @Raghunandan yea I also took that out but still give me an error

Comment: what was the error? post the stack trace

Comment: @Raghunandan nullpointerexception

Comment: post the stack trace and post the line tht caused NPE

Comment: your `itemPositionView` is null this `customAdapter.getView(position, null, result_list)` returns null. check it and where do you view in onItemClick?

Comment: nope it is null when I use the parameter of the View onclick not that one, and pass it to ontouchlistener

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39236/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user2844805)